# NoSuchMethodError: No static method create [Android] [Dagger]

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, dagger

I have some small android libraries created for modularizing the app code. One of these libraries (**libraryA**) has some Activities and those are mentioned inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the library. The problem I face with this is that when I ship an SDK that is built on top of **libraryA**, I get the code of all the activities being shipped with **libraryA** even after running the proguard. This is obvious because this is how proguard works. But, I want only the activities, from **libraryA**, that the parent app wants to be used, to be shipped with the final apk.

To achieve the above behaviour, I have removed the activity declaration from the **libraryA** manifest file and added the needed activities, from **libraryA**, in the `app`'s manifest file. I am also using `Dagger` to build my dependency graph. When I run my application after making this change, the app crashes with the following exception which seems to be a `Dagger` generated issue.

```
2020-03-28 11:28:50.081 20177-20177/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: <mypackage>, PID: 20177
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method create(Ljavax/inject/Provider;Ljavax/inject/Provider;Ljavax/inject/Provider;Ljavax/inject/Provider;Ljavax/inject/Provider;Ljavax/inject/Provider;Ljavax/inject/Provider;)Ldagger/MembersInjector; in class Lin/apollo/android/ui/activity/MyMovedActivity_MembersInjector; or its super classes (declaration of 'in.apollo.android.ui.activity.MyMovedActivity_MembersInjector' appears in /data/app/<mypackage>-JGH6hd6Acb-8dr0QvrxKWA==/base.apk!classes5.dex)
        at in.apollo.android.di.DaggerApolloApplicationComponent$PinComponentImpl.initialize(DaggerApolloApplicationComponent.java:3267)
        at in.apollo.android.di.DaggerApolloApplicationComponent$PinComponentImpl.<init>(DaggerApolloApplicationComponent.java:3211)
        at in.apollo.android.di.DaggerApolloApplicationComponent$PinComponentImpl.<init>(DaggerApolloApplicationComponent.java:3187)
        at in.apollo.android.di.DaggerApolloApplicationComponent.pinComponent(DaggerApolloApplicationComponent.java:2650)
        at in.apollo.android.FinderApplication.onCreate(FinderApplication.java:167)
        at in.apollo.android.ApolloApplication.initializeSdk(ApolloApplication.java:264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6852)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1982)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Any idea why this might be happening and how can we address this?

Comment: Hi. We have similar issue. Did you manage to solve this?